# Docker - Editing Mount Options

Tags: docker, containers

I am adding a disk quota to my Ubuntu docker container. To add quota support, I need to edit the mount options and add `usrquota` as explained here: [how-to-enable-user-and-group-quotas](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-enable-user-and-group-quotas)

Usually you would edit `/etc/fstab` and add the mount option.

My question, how would I add a mount option to a docker container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really mount container's disks anywhere. There is a feature request asking for setting quotas in Docker containers (https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3804) so at the moment there is no easy way.

However, apparently there are a couple of workarounds.

**Use Device Mapper as a limit**

Docker containers have a maximum of 10GB of disk space, per container (that is the Device Mapper storage driver by default).

So your best option is to change the default value for new containers, but then, it is my understanding you would need to rebuild the containers.

So, if you want to enforce 5 gigabytes, you would write

```
docker -d --storage-opt dm.basesize=5G
```

Source

https://goldmann.pl/blog/2014/09/11/resource-management-in-docker/#_limiting_disk_space

**User inside/quota outside**

The trick is create a specific user account in each container, and assign a *userid* for that account (and obviously run the command with that account).
On the host, we would use `setquota` to limit this *userid*.

Source https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/471#issuecomment-22373948

Comment: Thanks for your response @gonfva. I use volumes to hold my data, which means the Device Mapper limit doesn't apply. The second option would be a bit of a pain to integrate into my current system. I think it may be best to wait until Docker adds quota support!